# SonarQube. Custom rule needs to access to file

Tags: java, sonarqube

I implemented rule where I needed to extract data from external file. I put this file in resources folder and extract it with the following construction:

`CustomRuleCheck.class.getResource(/com/packagename/file.json)`

During JUnit testing is everething ok, but when I run an integration testing I cannot get this file.

`ava.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/username/.sonar/cache/587ed81cbc083da501c4bfdcefd65f35/sonar-plugin-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar_unzip/META-INF/lib/custom-checks-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/packagename/file.json (No such file or directory)`

I followed to pointed url and it turned out that folder `/home/username/.sonar/cache/587ed81cbc083da501c4bfdcefd65f35/sonar-plugin-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar_unzip/META-INF/lib/` contains `custom-checks-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar` and this jar has necessary file inside. 
And I don't have any idea how to extract this. Could you help me please?

Comment: You are probablly  retriving the resource from diferent context during unit tests. Are you loading the resource from custom-checks-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar code or from sonar-plugin-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar code ? To acces resource you should use class or classloader that belongs to package where the resource is located.

Comment: @JosefProcházka I implemented the rule that is placed into `custom-checks` plugin and  I have a resource folder with my json here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood,(thanks to @JosefProcházka) `sonar-plugin` loads CustomRules in runtime uploading the particular rules from `custom-checks.jar`.
I find a decision how extract resource files from `custom-checks.jar` in CustomRules (Custom rules is placed in `checks.jar`).
I've written down the following util method:

```
public class JarResourcesUtils {

    public static File extractFileFromJar(String path) throws IOException {
        String resourcePath = JarResourcesUtils.class.getResource(path).getPath();
        String jarPath = resourcePath.replace("!" + path, "").replace("file:", "");

        try (JarFile jarFile  = new JarFile(jarPath)){
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();

            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
              JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
              String entryName = "/" + entry.getName();
              if (entryName.equals(path)) {
                  InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                  File file = File.createTempFile(entryName.replaceAll("//", "_"), ".tmp");
                  FileUtils.copyToFile(inputStream, file);
                  return file;
              }
           }
           return null;
         }
     }
}
```

Then inside a CustomRules we can get this file:

```
File resourceFile = JarResourcesUtils.extractFileFromJar("/com/packagename/file.json");
```

Of cource, file must be placed in resources directory according to maven conventions